# Looking for dataset of trajectory data consisting of latitude, longitude, altitude and time

Tags: rockets, trajectory, aerodynamics, launch-trajectories

I am working on a project in which I need to cluster trajectories of different type of flying objects like rocket, plane, missile, etc.

For that I am looking for a database or data-set which contains

- Latitude
- Longitude
- Altitude
- Time

Does any one have seen these type of database before? Or anyone know how I can get such data?

Comment: For satellites, you can get TLEs from e.g. https://celestrak.com/

Answer (score 2):

**Earth Satellites:** get [TLEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) from [Celestrak](https://celestrak.org/) or [Space-Track](https://www.space-track.org/auth/login) and propagate them with [SGP4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_perturbations_models). One way to do that and to also calculate their ground tracks (latitude and longitude) is the Python package [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) but there may be others. However I'm not aware of proper databases that you can download constantly updated positions already calculated each second. Things in orbit move at from several to almost 8 kilometers a second, so you need to recalculate constantly.

**Rockets:** for a compilation of almost every launch see [Jonathan's Space Home Page](http://planet4589.org/space/) compiled by [Jonathan McDowell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_McDowell) (also possibly [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21168/12102)) but you may have to reconstruct their launch trajectories yourself.

**Planes:** [Flightradar24.com](https://www.flightradar24.com/)

**Missiles:** These are generally not planned in advance, over with fairly quickly, and details are not usually entered into a public database.

**Additional resources:** for natural celestial bodies and artificial spacecraft in deep space can be found at JPL's [Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) and even more options are catalogued in Astronomy Stack Exchange's [Where can I find/visualize planets/stars/moons/etc positions?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982).